# Azure Devops CLI To Query Pipeline Agent Pool Security Roles

Tags: azure, azure-devops, command-line-interface, azure-cli

I am trying to get security roles and permissions for agent pools using azure cli, is there a way to get these?

[image]

I want to get higlighted users/groups list as well as roles and access levels through Azure cli commands.Can any one help me out on this?

[image: I want to get the higlited groups and respective roles and access levels using azure cli commands]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the test, we haven't found the direct cli command to query the user list of agent pools, but we managed to query the result via the rest api

========================================================

**Updated on 11/11**

Below is for **orgnization-level** agent pool permission

`get https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.agentpoolrole/roleassignments/resources/{agent_pool_ID}?api-version=6.0-preview.1`

[image]

Below is for **project-level** agent pool permission

`get https://dev.azure.com/{orgName}/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.agentqueuerole/roleassignments/resources/{ProjectID}_{QueueID}?api-version=6.0-preview.1`

[image]

You can get the {QueueID} from the project agent pool url.
[image]

========================================================

**Updated** on **11/15**

You could check the query entries from the `200` status result for the related records and test to modify the full rest api (sometime by lucky-draws).
[image]

Comment: https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.agentpoolrole/roleassignments/resources/{agent_pool_ID}?api-version=6.0-preview.1-----> This is giving me permissions at organisation level, is there a way to get Project level permissions ?

Comment: @Sandeep i have updated the answer and you can check again to see if it resolves your issue

Comment: If you provide reference links,that will be helpful,Anyways Thanks @Ceeno

Comment: @Sandeep , hi during the investigations, i didn't get this from official document, but from browser network trace logs in developer mode(F12 in your browser). most operations on the pages could be recorded in [network trace logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/howto-troubleshoot-network-trace) with rest api.